# Laravel Gate Definition Clarification

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have 2 roles

`User Profile Manager` and `Reward Manager`

**User Profile Manager** can access all the user related actions but not reward related.

**Reward Manager** can access some of user related but all the reward related.

I have defined following gates

```
// Allows Super Admin and User Profile Manager all user-management actions but denies all reward related.

Gate::define('user-management', function ($user) {
    return ($user->hasRole('Super Admin') || $user->hasRole('User Profile Manager'));
});

// Allow Super Admin and Reward Manager all reward-management but denies all user related.

Gate::define('reward-management', function ($user) {
    return ($user->hasRole('Super Admin') || $user->hasRole('Reward Manager')) ;
});
```

My routes and its middleware given below.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'can:user-management'], function() {

    Route::get('users/getusers', 'UserController@getUsers');
    Route::post('sendnotification', 'UserController@sendNotification');

});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'can:reward-management'], function() {

    Route::get('users/getRewardPoints/{userId}', 'UserController@getRewardPoints');
    Route::post('users/manageRewardPoints', 'UserController@manageRewardPoints');

});
```

I want to rewrite this in such a way that I have explained above. How can I achieve this? Am I doing it in right way?

Comment: you can show hasRole() method ?

Comment: public function role() {

        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\AdminUserRole', 'id', 'role');
    }

    /**
     * Find out if user has a specific role
     *
     * $return boolean
     */
    public function hasRole($check) {

        $role = $this->role()->get();
        return in_array($check, array_pluck($role, 'role_name'));
    }

Comment: you can use self middleware